# shell scripts: pass curl result as parameter to shell script

Tags: shell, curl

I want to pass the curl result as parameter to the another script say the script `delete-app.sh`

```
 #!/bin/sh

SERVICE_HOST=localhost
SERVICE_PORT=9200

delete(){
    echo "entered  here"
    if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "usage: $0 delete [--name] [index_name]"
        exit 1
    fi

    case "$1" in
        --name)
            index_name=$2
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Unknown argument $1"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    echo $index_name
}


if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 (delete)"
    exit 1
fi

case "$1" in
  delete)
    delete $2 $3
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unknown argument $1"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

running the below command

```
 ./delete_app.sh delete --name `curl -s "http://<host>:<port>/_cat/indices/applicationevent*" | awk -F ' ' '{print $3}' | cut -c18- | awk -v d=`date -d'10 days ago' +'%Y.%m.%d'` -F'|' '$1 < d' | awk '{print "applicationevent-" $1 }' |paste -s -d, -
```

here the parameters which i gets for --name is from curl command result, but now the result is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

the below way is working fine

```
./delete_app.sh delete --name $(curl -s "http://<host>:<port>/_cat/indices/applicationevent*" | awk -F ' ' '{print $3}' | cut -c18- | awk -v d=`date -d'10 days ago' +'%Y.%m.%d'` -F'|' '$1 < d' | awk '{print "applicationevent-" $1 }' |paste -s -d, -)
```